# Let's create a [digital] hell for this tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [digital](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital) tag has 309 questions at the moment, 3.3k followers, and no tag wiki.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, not at all. It's mostly used instead of (or with) [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature), but it gets tagged for questions with entirely different topics as well.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Since *most* of programming is done digitally, it kind of is. (I have my respect for punch card users though.)

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it's totally superfluous.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. As I described earlier, it can mean anything.

Comment: So what about [users who ask about circuitry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186952/synthesizable-ff-in-verilog-with-active-low-reset) and have programming questions around that?

Comment: It has 644 followers.  Not terribly obvious why it is so popular, but there are a fair number of users with an EE degree interested in the kind of programming required in [vhdl] or [verilog].  I vaguely remember a failed attempt at creating a dedicated stackexchange site to find them a more welcome home, didn't work.

Comment: If it stays, we should raise an 'Analogue' tag.

Answer (score 9):

I just did a quick survey of the tag. We have questions about:

- Digital logic gates
- Boolean algebra
- Digital signal processing
- Google Digital Garage training program
- Digital clocks (e.g. outputting time in `hh:mm:ss` format)
- Digital downloads
- Digital signatures (e.g. for banking)
- Digital signage and displays
- Numerical digits in number systems (more a math thing than programming)
- Digital (non-analog) hardware interfaces, such as serial ports

This tag has no real meaning other than its dictionary one (of or relating to fingers, and metaphorically to things that can be counted on fingers). It may have been useful in the days when people thought wearing digital watches was a pretty neat idea, but no more. Burninate and retag with more appropriate tags.

Comment: An [HHGTTG reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnI62dsOKDo&t=0m20s)...

Comment: Re-posting my (previous) Comment without Abbreviations: Nice "Survey", but posted 4 years after the Thread was started makes it a bit "confusing" I would think..., you could mention the "new" Numbers (July 2022): 185->307 Questions + 664->3.3k Watchers. // + Interesting would also be some (approx) Numbers/Stats with how many Questions in the 10 Categories you've identified, + maybe which Tags could be (recommended to be) used in each of them... :idea: